# Apache Ignite : Caused by: Local node's binary configuration is not equal to remote node's binary configuration

Tags: ignite

I am trying to access ignite from Java using the following code :

```
public class IgniteTestWithIgniteCluster {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try  {
        System.out.println();
        Ignite ignite = Ignition.start();
        ClusterNode clusterNode = ignite.cluster().node(UUID.fromString("4E73716D-E87A-42B8-B141-B9083F70C8A1"));
        ignite.cluster().active(true);
        System.out.println(">>> Thin client put-get example started.");

        final String CACHE_NAME = "put-get-example";
        IgniteCache<Integer,Address> cache = ignite.getOrCreateCache(CACHE_NAME);

        System.out.format(">>> Created cache [%s].\n", CACHE_NAME);

        Integer key = 1;

        Address val = new Address("1545 Jackson Street", 94612);

        cache.put(key, val);

        System.out.format(">>> Saved [%s] in the cache.\n", val);

        Address cachedVal = cache.get(key);

        System.out.format(">>> Loaded [%s] from the cache.\n", cachedVal);
    }
    catch (ClientException e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.format("Unexpected failure: %s\n", e);
    }
}
```

}

Error :

```
class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to start manager: GridManagerAdapter [enabled=true, name=org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager]
at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.startManager(IgniteKernal.java:1726)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.start(IgniteKernal.java:1028)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start0(IgnitionEx.java:2014)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start(IgnitionEx.java:1723)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start0(IgnitionEx.java:1151)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.startConfigurations(IgnitionEx.java:1069)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:955)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:854)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:578)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:558)
at org.apache.ignite.Ignition.start(Ignition.java:309)
at ignite.IgniteTest.main(IgniteTest.java:23)
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to start SPI: TcpDiscoverySpi [addrRslvr=null, sockTimeout=5000, ackTimeout=5000, marsh=JdkMarshaller [clsFilter=org.apache.ignite.marshaller.MarshallerUtils$1@1b2c4efb], reconCnt=10, reconDelay=2000, maxAckTimeout=600000, forceSrvMode=false, clientReconnectDisabled=false, internalLsnr=null]
at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.GridManagerAdapter.startSpi(GridManagerAdapter.java:300)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager.start(GridDiscoveryManager.java:915)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.startManager(IgniteKernal.java:1721)
... 11 more   

Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiException: Local node's binary configuration is not equal to remote node's binary configuration [locNodeId=7f781341-68dd-440d-a6d1-040bf4ab5fb6, rmtNodeId=4e73716d-e87a-42b8-b141-b9083f70c8a1, locBinaryCfg=null, rmtBinaryCfg={globIdMapper=org.apache.ignite.binary.BinaryBasicIdMapper, compactFooter=false, globSerializer=null}]
at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi.checkFailedError(TcpDiscoverySpi.java:1874)
at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl.joinTopology(ServerImpl.java:949)
at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl.spiStart(ServerImpl.java:373)
at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi.spiStart(TcpDiscoverySpi.java:1948)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.GridManagerAdapter.startSpi(GridManagerAdapter.java:297)
... 13 more
```

The nodeid "**4E73716D-E87A-42B8-B141-B9083F70C8A1"** is the instance id i got when i instantiated ignite.

Instantiated the Ignite with the following spring xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

<!--<bean id="loadBalancingPolicy" class="com.datastax.driver.core.policies.RoundRobinPolicy"/>-->

<bean class="com.harman.inca.config.HoconPlaceholderConfigurer"/>


<bean id="ignite.cfg" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">

    <property name="peerClassLoadingEnabled" value="false"/>
    <property name="dataStorageConfiguration">
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataStorageConfiguration">
            <property name="walMode" value="NONE"/>
            <property name="walArchivePath" value="D:\work\TIWorkspace\ignite\wal\archive"/>
            <property name="defaultDataRegionConfiguration">
                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataRegionConfiguration">
                    <property name="persistenceEnabled" value="true"/>
                    <!-- Increasing the buffer size to 1 GB. -->
                    <property name="checkpointPageBufferSize"
                              value="#{1024L * 1024 * 1024}"/>
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="binaryConfiguration">
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.BinaryConfiguration">
            <property name="compactFooter" value="false"/>

            <property name="idMapper">
                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.binary.BinaryBasicIdMapper">
                    <property name="lowerCase" value="true"/>
                </bean>
            </property>

            <property name="nameMapper">
                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.binary.BinaryBasicNameMapper">
                    <property name="simpleName" value="true"/>
                </bean>
            </property>


        </bean>
    </property>


    <property name="includeEventTypes">
        <list>
            <!--Task execution events-->
            <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_TASK_STARTED"/>
            <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_TASK_FINISHED"/>
            <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_TASK_FAILED"/>
            <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_TASK_TIMEDOUT"/>
            <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_TASK_SESSION_ATTR_SET"/>
            <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_TASK_REDUCED"/>

            <!--Cache events-->
            <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_CACHE_OBJECT_PUT"/>
            <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_CACHE_OBJECT_READ"/>
            <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_CACHE_OBJECT_REMOVED"/>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="discoverySpi">
      <!--  <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.zk.ZookeeperDiscoverySpi">
            <property name="zkConnectionString" value="localhost:2181"/>
            &lt;!&ndash;<property name="zkConnectionString" value="${zookeeper.server}"/>&ndash;&gt;
            <property name="zkRootPath" value="/dbobjects"/>
        </bean>-->
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
            <property name="ipFinder">
                <!--
                    Ignite provides several options for automatic discovery that can be used
                    instead os static IP based discovery. For information on all options refer
                    to our documentation: http://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/cluster-config
                -->
                <!-- Uncomment static IP finder to enable static-based discovery of initial nodes. -->
                <!--<bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.vm.TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder">-->
                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.multicast.TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder">
                    <property name="addresses">
                        <list>
                            <!-- In distributed environment, replace with actual host IP address. -->
                            <value>127.0.0.1:47500..47509</value>
                        </list>
                    </property>
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>

</bean>
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location">
        <value>classpath:application.properties</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the same config when starting your second Ignite instance with `Ignition.start()`. Either supply path to XML file, or translate this XML to Java configuration.